# F3 return query result

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

I try to build a REST interface using the Fat Free Framework. 
I use the following code to query the database:

```
$product = new DB\SQL\Mapper($this->db, 'product');
$product->load(array('id=?', $this->productID));
```

I can now return for instance the title with

```
echo json_encode($product->title);
```

But how do I return the whole row? The following won't work

```
echo json_encode($product);
```

Comment: how looks your $product object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it.
Had to use

```
echo json_encode($product->cast());
```